# PHP JSON data to HTML conversion

Tags: php, html, json, dom

I need to convert JSON data to HTML format. I have problems in adding child elements in correct order. All elements are added sequentially but the order should be as in the JSON structure. How can I append in the correct order?

Example JSON:

```
{
    "tag": "html",
    "children": [
        {
            "tag": "body",
            "children": [
                {
                    "tag": "form",
                    "class": "form-horizontal",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "tag": "fieldset",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "tag": "legend",
                                    "html": "Form Name"
                                },
                                {
                                    "tag": "div",
                                    "class": "control-group",
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "tag": "label",
                                            "class": "control-label",
                                            "for": "textinput-0",
                                            "html": "Text Input"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "tag": "div",
                                            "class": "controls",
                                            "children": [
                                                {
                                                    "tag": "input",
                                                    "id": "textinput-0",
                                                    "name": "textinput-0",
                                                    "type": "text",
                                                    "placeholder": "placeholder",
                                                    "class": "input-xlarge"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "tag": "p",
                                                    "class": "help-block",
                                                    "html": "help"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "tag": "div",
                                    "class": "control-group",
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "tag": "label",
                                            "class": "control-label",
                                            "for": "singlebutton-0",
                                            "html": "Single Button"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "tag": "div",
                                            "class": "controls",
                                            "children": [
                                                {
                                                    "tag": "button",
                                                    "id": "singlebutton-0",
                                                    "name": "singlebutton-0",
                                                    "class": "btn btn-primary",
                                                    "html": "Button"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What I got so far:

```
<html><body>
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>
<legend>Form Name
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="textinput-0">Text Input
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="textinput-0" name="textinput-0" type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="input-xlarge">
  </div>
  </label>
</div>
</legend>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body></html>
```

Correct output should be:

```
<html><body>
<form class="form-horizontal" >
<fieldset>
<legend>Form Name</legend>
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="textinput-0">Text Input</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="textinput-0" name="textinput-0" type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="input-xlarge">
    <p class="help-block">help</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="singlebutton-0">Single Button</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <button id="singlebutton-0" name="singlebutton-0" class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body></html>
```

My PHP code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$rootelem = $dom;

$obj = json_decode($json_content, true);
parse_to_html($obj);

function parse_to_html($arr) {
    global $dom;
    global $rootelem;

    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
            parse_to_html($val);
        } else {
            if ($key == "tag") {
                $rootelem = $rootelem->appendChild($dom->createElement($val));
            } else if ($key == "html") {
                $rootelem->textContent = $val;
            } else { //attribute
                $domAttribute = $dom->createAttribute($key);
                $domAttribute->value = $val;
                $rootelem->appendChild($domAttribute);
            }
        }
    }
}

$dom->formatOutput = true;
print $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: The people who will try to help you deserve a minimum consideration. Can you please correctly format the "What I got so far" section? It is unreadable in only two lines.

Comment: @AlFoиceѫ sure, done.

Comment: Following the same format as the intended result also helps. Now it's done

Comment: your document appears to be missing the required `head`

Comment: @RamRaider As this was a prototype I didn't add the head tag. I don't think that it will matter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own solution. I added a `$level` parameter which holds the level of the item in the array. So I can append to the corresponding element. Also a global `$nod` array that refers to created nodes.

```
function parse_to_html($arr, $level = 1) {
    global $dom;
    global $nod;

    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
            parse_to_html($val, $level + 1);
        } else {
            if ($key == "tag") {
                $nod[$level] = $dom->createElement($val);
                $nod[$level-2]->appendChild($nod[$level]);
            } else if ($key == "html") {
                $nod[$level]->nodeValue = $val;
            } else { //attribute
                $domAttribute = $dom->createAttribute($key);
                $domAttribute->value = $val;
                $nod[$level]->appendChild($domAttribute);
            }

        }
    }
}
```